# What should be my DNS settings?

Tags: samba, dns-server

I have a samba server and it is on the same network as the clients which I want to connect to the servers domain.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to see the server. I can access its web server via my browser and have even tried putting my preferred DNS server as the ip of the server but still no luck.

Settings (These are examples to give your some numbers to work with):

```
Client: 192.168.1.34
Server: 192.168.1.64
Default Gateway for network: 192.168.1.45
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you saying you are having connecting from a Windows client to a Linux Samba server? What do you mean by `see` the server? Have you tried connecting by IP? Like `\\192.165.34.2` from the file manager?

Comment: No. I have not tried connecting via ip  and the client says it cant contact the server. I am trying to connect client to server via domain join in windows

Comment: If you can get to it via a web browser it sounds like your network and DNS are ok.  Have you looked at the firewall settings on the samba server?  There are a few ports that need to be open.

Comment: No. I haven't post those further details as answer and I will look at it

Comment: Perhaps if you post your actual IP addresses, we may be able to help you.

Comment: @CraigWatson Why would that help?

Comment: Because at the moment, we have no idea whether the addresses you have posted are accurate representations of your infrastructure, or if they're just random numbers plucked from mid-air to give us some examples. All of the IPs are actually in the public address space, for example, and are spread across the UK, US and Italy.

Comment: @CraigWatson Fair enough but I don't want to compromise security of my network

Comment: @IsaacWalker-cox if you're running an internal private (i.e. not publicly accessible) network, posting your IP addresses won't compromise the security of the network, and is actively encouraged to help the accuracy of answers on ServerFault.

Comment: @CraigWatson Can't you just use the examples I gave. I don't even know if these are real ips

Comment: @IsaacWalker-cox are all three devices on completely separate IP ranges in real life? Examples are only appropriate if they are accurate representations of your own setup. Picking IPs out of thin air will do nothing but cloud your question.

Comment: @CraigWatson All the devices are on the same subnet. I have updated post to represent that.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an issue with router/firewall config rather than DNS.

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-23 08:07 CDT
Nmap scan report for static-192-165-34-2.cust.crystone.se         (192.165.34.2)
Host is up (0.26s latency).
Not shown: 986 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
25/tcp   open   smtp
26/tcp   closed rsftp
53/tcp   open   domain
80/tcp   open   http
110/tcp  open   pop3
143/tcp  open   imap
443/tcp  open   https
465/tcp  open   smtps
993/tcp  open   imaps
995/tcp  open   pop3s
3306/tcp open   mysql
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

You need to have TCP ports 139 and 445 and UDP ports 137 and 138 opened, and make sure Samba is listening on those ports.

[Edit:] I don't have enough rep to comment, but it shouldn't matter that the two systems are on a local network.  This is usually handled at the server level and can be verified with a combination of iptables and netstat command options.  Regardless, if you are not the network or system administrator, then you should probably be getting in touch with them instead.

Comment: But I  am not  the network administrator

Comment: Also, both server and client are on local network